# How to properly perform state update on a large matrix?

Tags: reactjs

I've been stuck on this problem for several days, which is why I come here for help.
I'm trying to build a maze generator, where the user can interact with a grid to set some square as walls, traps, etc...

**Approach that seemed like it should work but failed :**

All the logic is handled by a parent component, which passes down a state matrix to a grid render component. I like this approach because the UI doesn't handle the logic, but it gets extremely laggy when the grid gets big.

Logical component :

```
    export default function MazeMaker({
        stateToColorInterpreter,
        getGenerationResult,
        squareSize,
        initialValues
    }: MazeMakerProps){

        // Creating the initial state

        const initialStart = initialValues?.start ?? {row: 4, col: 8};
        const initialTarget = initialValues?.target?? {row: 3, col: 2};
        const initialGrid = initialValues?.grid ?? generateMatrix<MazeNodeState>(MazeNodeState.EMPTY, 20, 40);
        initialGrid[initialStart.row][initialStart.col] = MazeNodeState.START;
        initialGrid[initialTarget.row][initialTarget.col] = MazeNodeState.TARGET;
    
        const [stateMatrix, setStateMatrix] = useState<MazeNodeState[][]>(initialGrid.map(row => row.map(state => state)));
        const [start, setStart] = useState<Coordinate>(initialStart);
        const [target, setTarget] = useState<Coordinate>(initialTarget);
        const [placingType, setPlacingType] = useState<MazeNodeState>(MazeNodeState.BLOCKED);
        const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
        // Updates a square state in the generated grid based on passed coords and state.
        const setSquareState = (coord: Coordinate, state: MazeNodeState) => {

            // Execute some logic and update the state matrix, then update the state with shallow-copy
            stateMatrix[coord.row][coord.col] = state;
            setStateMatrix([...stateMatrix])
        }
    
        return(
        <div onMouseDown={() => setIsMouseDown(true)}
             onMouseLeave={() => setIsMouseDown(false)}
             onMouseUp={() => setIsMouseDown(false)}
        >
            <Grid
                stateMatrix={stateMatrix}
                stateToColor={stateToColorInterpreter}
                onSquareMouseDown = {(x: number, y: number) => {setSquareState({row: x, col: y}, placingType)}}
                onSquareClick = {(x: number, y: number) => {setSquareState({row: x, col: y}, placingType)}}
                onSquareMouseEnter = {(x: number, y: number) => {if(isMouseDown) setSquareState({row: x, col: y}, placingType)}}
            />
            <div>
                // State picker so that the user can what kind of block they want to place, updates the placingType state
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Grid component :

```
        export default function Grid({
        stateMatrix,
        stateToColor,
        onSquareClick,
        onSquareMouseEnter,
        onSquareMouseDown,
    }: GridProps){
        const rows = stateMatrix.length;
        const cols = stateMatrix[0].length;
    
        return(
                <GridDiv // Styled component
                    rows = {rows}
                    cols = {cols}
                >
                    {
                        Array.from({length: rows}).map((_, rowIndex) => <Row key={rowIndex}>
                            {Array.from({length: cols}).map((_, colIndex) =>
                                <Square
                                key={rowIndex * rows + colIndex}
                                state={stateMatrix[rowIndex][colIndex]}
                                stateToColor={stateToColor}
                                onClick={() => {if(onSquareClick) onSquareClick(rowIndex, colIndex)}}
                                onMouseEnter={() => {if(onSquareMouseEnter) onSquareMouseEnter(rowIndex, colIndex)}}
                                onMouseDown={() => {if(onSquareMouseDown) onSquareMouseDown(rowIndex, colIndex)}}
                                />)}
                        </Row>)
                    }
                </GridDiv>
        )
    }
```

Square component :

```
    export default function Square({
        state,
        stateToColor,
        onClick,
        onMouseDown,
        onMouseEnter,
    }: SquareProps){
        const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState<string>(stateToColor(state));
        const [nextColor, setNextColor] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
        const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState<number>(state);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if(state !== currentState){
                if(nextColor) setBackgroundColor(nextColor);
                setNextColor(stateToColor(state))
            }
            setCurrentState(state);
        }, [state]);
    
        return(
            <SquareDiv // Styled component
                color = {backgroundColor}
                nextColor = {nextColor}
                animationDurationMs={300}
                onMouseDown = {() => {if(onMouseDown){onMouseDown();}}}
                onMouseEnter = {() => {if(onMouseEnter) {onMouseEnter(); }}}
                onClick = {onClick}
            />
        )
    }
```

**Approach that worked but that I do not like**

What worked was to make each square aware of the state it should switch to upon being clicked upon.
I strongly dislike this approach because the UI component has to do some logic, so it doesn't seem flexible or reusable. The grid and logic component are the same expect they pass down the "newStateType" and "shouldUpdate", and the square updates itself when the mouse is dragged over based on these.

```
export default function Square({
    stateRef,
    stateToColor,
    onClick,
    onMouseDown,
    onMouseEnter,
    newStateType,
    shouldUpdate,
}: SquareProps){
    const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState<string>(stateToColor(stateRef.current));
    const [nextColor, setNextColor] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const [state, setState] = useState<number>(stateRef.current);
    const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState<number>(stateRef.current);

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(stateRef.current);
    }, [stateRef.current]);


    useEffect(() => {
        if(state !== currentState){
            if(nextColor) setBackgroundColor(nextColor);
            setNextColor(stateToColor(state))
        }
        setCurrentState(state);
    }, [state]);

    return(
        <SquareDiv
            color = {backgroundColor}
            nextColor = {nextColor}
            animationDurationMs={300}
            onMouseDown = {() => {if(onMouseDown){onMouseDown();
                if(newStateType) setState(newStateType)}}}
            onMouseEnter = {() => {
            if(onMouseEnter) {
                onMouseEnter();
                if(shouldUpdate) setState(newStateType ?? 0)}}}
            onClick = {onClick}
        />
    )
}
```

I'm lost as to why the performance is so drastically better when the square changes itself rather than the logic being handled by a parent component, and I have no idea how to create an approach that would get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm posting my answer for anyone finding themselves in the same situation later down the road.

The reason why the grid is so laggy when using the "classic" approach, is that in order to perform a re-render, what React does is comparing the previous state to the current state, and re-rendering whatever needs to be re-rendered.

In the case of a 50x50 grid, with 2500 nodes, this comparison is somewhat expensive, and makes everything laggy when it needs to be performed a lot.

The alternative, in our case, because we know exactly which node we need to update, is to do that modification imperatively rather than declaratively as we normally do with react. In order to do that, we can make use of ForwardRefs and useImperativeHandle. For more information about these, check the official documentation, or these handy tutorials : https://codezup.com/forwardref-in-functional-components-react-hooks/ , https://codezup.com/how-to-use-useimperativehandle-react-hook-example/